# If $p - a \equiv -a \pmod{p}$ then what is $\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv ? \pmod{p}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p - a \equiv -a \pmod{p}$ then what is $\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv ? \pmod{p}$? Where $p$ is an odd prime.

I read in the book, they claimed:
$$p - 1 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$
$$p - 2 \equiv -2 \pmod{p}$$
$$p - 3 \equiv -3 \pmod{p}$$
$$ ... $$
$$\frac{p - 1}{2} \equiv -(\frac{p - 1}{2}) \pmod{p}$$

However, I realized that the last statement was wrong because if it's true then:
$$\frac{p - 1}{2} + \frac{p - 1}{2}\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
$$p - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

[image: This is my scan version from the book 6th edition]
Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Well, of course it's wrong. Which book claimed this?

Comment: Well, it's the inverse of $-2$ modulo $p$. In other words $(-2)\cdot\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 1 \mod p$. The last step of your sequence of equalities mod $p$ should be $\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv -\frac{p+1}{2}$ by the way.

Comment: I dont understand your question $\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv \frac{p-1}{2} \pmod{p}$ or $\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv -\frac{p+1}{2} \pmod{p}$

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Elementary Number Theory and Its application by Kenneth H. Rosen. I've just bought it from the library today :(.

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: $\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv -\frac{p-1}{2} \pmod{p}$ was from the book. I don't know what does the rhs equal to.

Comment: @Chan: Do you have the book right in front of you? Are you *positive* it says that, and not $-\frac{p+1}{2}$ on the right hand side?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Yes, I'm 100% positive. It must be a typo, I guess.

Comment: @Chan: I have the ebook. Could you tell me the page number of the book?

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: What's your edition? Mine is 6th edition. It's in the back of the book page 673, problem 31.

Comment: Mine is the 5th edition. Can you give the chapter number and section number and the exercise number

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: Mine is chapter 6, section 6.1 exercises, exercise number is 31.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence as written doesn't make sense, since the last term does not follow the pattern of the previous ones. However, you *can* argue that
$$p - \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right) \equiv -\frac{p-1}{2}\pmod{p}.$$
This *does* follow the same pattern as the rest of the terms.

And since
$$p - \frac{p-1}{2} = \frac{2p-p+1}{2} = \frac{p+1}{2}$$
then you have that
$$\frac{p+1}{2}\equiv -\frac{p-1}{2}\pmod{p},$$
hence $\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv -\frac{p+1}{2}\pmod{p}$.

Or peharps, it went like this:
\begin{align*}
p-1 &\equiv -1\pmod{p}\\
p-2 &\equiv -2 \pmod{p}\\
&\vdots\\
\frac{p-1}{2} = p-\left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right) &\equiv -\frac{p+1}{2}\pmod{p}
\end{align*}
and you have the wrong sign in the numerator on the right hand side?

**Added.** So, the rest of the proof. According to the scans Sivaram has posted, this was part of the computation of $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!^2$. The idea then is that we can get $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$ by multiplying the terms on the right hand side, and then get it again by multiplying the terms on the left hand side. That is, we look at
\begin{align*}
p-1 &\equiv -1 \pmod{p}\\
p-2 &\equiv -2 \pmod{p}\\
&\vdots\\
p-\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right) &\equiv -\frac{p-1}{2}\pmod{p}
\end{align*}
and note that if $p\equiv 3\pmod{2}$, then we have an odd number of negative signs on the right hand side. So we have that:
$$(-1)\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! = (-1)\Bigl(1\times 2\times\cdots\times \frac{p-1}{2}\Bigr) \equiv (p-1)(p-2)\cdots\left(p - \frac{p-1}{2}\right)\pmod{p}.$$
Now, $p - \frac{p-1}{2} = \frac{p+1}{2} = \frac{p-1}{2}+1$. So therefore we have that:
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!^2 &= \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\\
&\equiv  \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\Biggl( -(p-1)(p-2)\cdots\left(\frac{p-1}{2}+1\right)\Biggr)\pmod{p}\\
&\equiv -\left(1\times 2\times 3\times\cdots\times\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\times\left(\frac{p-1}{2}+1\right)\times\cdots\times (p-1)\right)\pmod{p}\\
&\equiv -(p-1)!\pmod{p}.
\end{align*}
But we know that $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ by Wilson's Theorem, so
$$\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!^2 \equiv -(p-1)!\equiv -(-1) = 1\pmod{p},$$
so if we let $x = \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$, then $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. This means that $p|x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$, so either $p|x-1$ or $p|x+1$. that is, eithe $x\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ or $x\equiv-1\pmod{p}$; giving: 
$$\text{either }\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}\quad\text{or}\quad \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\equiv 1\pmod{p}.$$

Answer (score 1):

In the 5th edition, they have got the signs right, at least thats what the scanned version of the ebook says.

[image]

**EDIT**

We have $p-k \equiv -k \pmod{p}$ and hence $$ \prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (p-k) \equiv \prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (-k) \pmod{p}$$

Note that $$(p-1)! = \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} k \right) \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (p-k) \right)$$

Hence, $$(p-1)! \equiv \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} k \right) \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (p-k) \right) \pmod{p} \equiv \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} k \right) \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (-k) \right) \pmod{p}$$

Hence, $$(p-1)! \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} k \right)^2 \pmod{p}$$

$$\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} k \right) = \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$$

From Wilson's theorem, $$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$

Hence, $$-1 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \left[ \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! \right]^2 \pmod{p}$$

Hence, $$\left[ \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! \right]^2 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}  \pmod{p}$$

Hence, if $p = 4k+3$, then $$(-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}} = 1$$

Hence, if $p = 4k+3$, $$\left[ \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! \right]^2 \equiv 1  \pmod{p}$$

Comment: @Sivaram: Thanks; there's a plus there, at any rate...

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: I'm trying to understand the proof. So as you brought it up, could you help me understand this proof? I can ask another question if you don't mind because the lhs in your 5th edition doesn't make sense to me. How could it add up $\frac{p-1}{2}!$

Comment: @Chan: Look at my derivation again: $$\frac{p+1}{2} = p-\frac{p-1}{2}.$$ So you get$$\frac{p+1}{2} = p-\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv -\frac{p-1}{2}\pmod{p}.$$

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Many thanks, I did not realize they're related. Another question is that how the `rhs` equals to $!(p - 1)$? I could not see it.

Comment: @Chan: I have added the intermediate steps.

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: Thank you. You guys here are so nice, I really appreciate it. Once again, thanks Arturo Magidin.